# How to overcome "Conversion from 'Byte' to 'String' cannot occur in a constant expression." in VB?

Tags: vb.net, list, variables, constants, type-conversion

I have this code:

```
Public Class Beryllium
    Public Const AtomicNumber As Byte = 4
    Public Const Symbol As String = "Be"
    Public Const Name As String = "Beryllium"
    Public Const AtomicMass As Double = 9.012182

    Public Const List = AtomicNumber & vbNewLine & Symbol & vbNewLine & Name & vbNewLine & AtomicMass 'This line
End Class
```

I want to make a list out of all the constants (AtomicNumber, Symbol, Name and AtomicMass). I want to make the list also a constant. When I run the code above, I get an error highlighting AtomicNumber (on line on which I commented on "This line"). I tried .ToString() and CStr() but I get errors on both. Maybe there is a different way to make these constants one string or list (must be public and have new lines)? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a constant expression because a constant expression requires the value to be computed during compile time. However, the "ToString()" value of a double is not known at compile time, because ToString is a method run by the Double class during runtime. So, the compiler has no idea what it will end up returning. However, .NET has the `readonly` modifier to deal with cases like this. If you change your line to:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly List = AtomicNumber & vbNewLine & Symbol & vbNewLine & Name & vbNewLine & AtomicMass
```

You'll see it will work. This readonly field is computed as soon as the class is loaded into memory, and cannot be changed by any client, so it is almost equivalent to a const. The only difference being of course, you have some overhead of computing the value. Additionally, with consts, the compiler can perform some other optimizations, like literally substituting the constant value instead of dereferencing it. I.e., if your code says:

```
Public Const Name As String = "Beryllium"

If (something = Name)...
```

If you look at the compiled code, it will actually say:

```
If (something = "Beryllium")
```

Comment: +1, ideally you should also specify the List's data type (As String).

Comment: @aquinas By the way, I'm making a Class Library containing all the elements in the periodic table (and its properties and details). So I want to be able to use them in other applications. I made a Demo app and imported the Library. This is the code I use for a single element in the Library https://gist.github.com/2511416 . However, I want to use it as a .dll in other apps. So when I (before, when I used Const) typed in Helium., IntelliSense popped up with all the variables in that class. Now, that doesn't happen - could you PLEASE tell me why? I can't use the ReadOnly at all. Thanks.

Comment: And also, when I `Dim m As New Mendeleev.Helium` (the library is called Mendeleev) it works fine when I use `m.[whatever]`. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, because consts are shared for the class by default, but readonlys are not. Simple enough though. Change your code to: 

`Public Shared ReadOnly List = ...`

Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Damn, **thank you SO much!** _Not the first time StackOverflow made me feel and look stupid!_ Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Make `List` a read only property.

This will allow you to use `ToString()` on `AtomicNumber`.

```
Public ReadOnly Property List() As String
  Get
    Return AtomicNumber.ToString() & vbNewLine & Symbol & vbNewLine & Name & vbNewLine & AtomicMass
  End Get
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is great however I marked the other answer as the Accepted Answer due to the length and the user's points (of which you have more of). Thanks anyway, both of your answers are great! _Hope you understand._

Comment: @RafalChmiel - You are free to vote as you wish. When accepting an answer one should normally accept the answer that most helped with their question.